# Play an MP3 on click in NextJS

Tags: javascript, frameworks, next.js

I'm new with JS frameworks, I could be getting the function syntax wrong. This is what I have, the idea is that upon clicking the button it will play a quick audio file which is designated below the button in the Audio tags. Any idea how I can get this working?

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('a1');
    audio.play();
  }

  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='col'>
          <button onClick={play()}>Click</button>
          <audio id='a1' src='/static/src.mp3'></audio>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call the function with parenthesis but pass the reference. Try this:

```
   <button onClick={play}>Click</button>
```

Comment: It now returns the following error upon click `Unhandled Runtime Error
NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.`

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onClick={play}>Click</button>
<audio id='a1'>
  <source src='/static/src.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

maybe something's wrong with src, you can test this on your src https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-6.mp3

or maybe you can use `useRef` to target the element instead of `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try holding a ref to the `<audio />` tag with `useRef`:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const audioRef = useRef();

  const play = () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.play()
    } else {
      // Throw error
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={play}>Play</button>
      <audio ref={audioRef} src='/static/src.mp3' />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered errors with all the libraries that play sound in NextJS for some reason, and I still wanted an Audio Player that I could manage its state from the outside. I created an AudioPlayer component to handle that, with the "audio" tag that is accessed with react refs.

I'll try my best to explain the code snippets below.

You manage a "play" state in the parent component at determines whether the audio is played or not. Inside the AudioPlayer component, you track the value of that property with `useEffect`, and play the sound if the "play" state is indeed true. However, it requires a manual interaction from the user, like a click of a button or something. Otherwise, the browser just blocks it. After the audio is finished, the "play" property will be reset to false again. That way, when you trigger the sound to activate once again, the "play" state will change from `false` to `true`, and the AudioPlayer will detect that change and play the sound.

This approach has two main advantages:

1. Since it's a separate component, you can write much less code. That one's obvious.
2. You can manage the state of the AudioPlayer outside of it.

And it also has two main disadvantages:

1. The sound can only be activated when a user triggers it.
2. You cannot play the sound unless it's already over.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function AudioPlayer(props) {
  const audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.play) {
      playAudio();
    }
  }, [props.play]);

  const playAudio = () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.play();
    }
  };

  const handleAudioEnded = () => {
    // Call the callback function when the audio ends
    if (props.onFinish) {
      props.onFinish();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <audio ref={audioRef} controls className="hidden" onEnded={handleAudioEnded}>
        <source src={props.src} type="audio/mp3" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And you use it like this inside of the parent component:

```
// a state that determines whether the sound will play or not
const [playSubmitSound, setPlaySubmitSound] = useState(false);

return (
        <AudioPlayer
          src="/sounds/submit.mp3"
          play={playSubmitSound}
          onFinish={() => setPlaySubmitSound(false)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => setPlaySubmitSound(true)}>sound</button>);
```

**Note:** I'm also using TailwindCSS to hide the Audio tag. You can do it simply with plain CSS by setting the `display` property of the wrapping div of the audio tag to `none`.